# Remove optional parameter in POST body Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a situation where in a web service call is made from two separate situations. The post body has 2 optional parameters. The two parameters needs to be present in one situation and in the other situation it should not be present.

Example:-

Situation 1 Post Body:-

```
{
    "parameter1" : "data1",
    "parameter2" : "data2",
    "parameter3" : "data3",
    "parameter4" : "data4"
}
```

Situation 2 Post Body:-

```
{
    "parameter1" : "data1",
    "parameter2" : "data2",
    "parameter3" : "data3",
    "parameter4" : "data4",
    "parameter5" : "data5",
    "parameter6" : "data6"
}
```

How do I achieve this using retrofit and Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

The Object you use to model your POST body should be annotated with

`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

above the class declaration and then from there just leave

```
 "parameter5" : "data5",
 "parameter6" : "data6"
```

null, they should not be serialized.

Comment: what retrofit does this work with ? i tried it on retrofit 2.0 but it didnt work.

Comment: How are you annotating your object model? It should work with all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is that we need to use hashMap for this kind of optional parameter approach.

for your example.

```
val req: HashMap<String,Any?> =HashMap()
req["parameter1"] = "value1"
req["parameter2"] = false // example boolean value as false in second param
req["parameter3"] = "value4"
req["parameter4"] = "value5"
if(someCondition==true) //condition to include remaining optional params
{
  req["parameter5"] = "value5"
  req["parameter6"] = "value6"
}
```

pass this `req` object as a request body in API call

Just for note (additional tip):

retrofit either keeps all null parameterized value or remove null parameter value, directly from the object, depending upon configuritation we set for `Convertor.Factory` value while building retrofit service object. This you can use in certain scenarios where null values not required or required.

```
 //to keep null value params in object
    val convertorFactory= GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create())    

//or

    // eliminate null params
    val convertorFactory= GsonConverterFactory.create()

    return Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(convertorFactory)
```